# sets and elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the universal set, $U=\{x:10≤x≤19,x\ \mathrm{is\ an\ integer}\}$, set $S=\{x:x\ \mathrm{is\ a\ multiple\ of}\ 4\}$, set $Q= \{x:x\ \mathrm{is\ an\ even\ number}\}$ and $S \subseteq Q$. Find

(a) set $(S \cup Q’)$.

(b) number of power set of $(S’ \cap R)$, given that $R \cap Q = \emptyset$.

My attempt :

i) $\{11,12,13,15,17,19\}$

ii) $n^2=32$

is this the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) {11,12,13,15,16,17,19}

and

b) It is not $n^2$, it is $2^n$

Answer (score 0):

Is i supposed to answer a?  What about $16$? For ii (presumably answering b), there are no integers $n$ such that $n^2=32$. How many elements does $S' \cap R$ have? No, it isn't $5$